# jquery !! compare two arrays?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to store the values of checkbox in a page while loading in a array and then maintain another array  of values of checkbox that have been updated.Further compare both these arrays and create another array

```
function Prevalue(id) {
    var Pre_checkList = [];
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var pThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");
        Pre_checkList += (Pre_checkList == "" ? pThisVal : "," + pThisVal);
    });
    id = Pre_checkList;
}

function Postvalue(id){
    var Post_checkList = [];
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        var pThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");
        Post_checkList += (Post_checkList == "" ? pThisVal : "," + pThisVal);
    });
    id = Post_checkList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the values in an array, you can use push(value); function.
Example: Post_checkList.push(pThisVal);

```
for(var i = 0; i < Pre_checkList.length; i++) {
   for(var j = 0; j < Post_checkList.length; j++) {
      // Comparison Condition 
   }
}
```

OR

```
var third_array = new Array();
$.each(Pre_checkList, function(i, val){
  if($.inArray(val, Post_checkList) < 0)
      third_array.push(val);
});
```